# React Context not getting updated on first click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Hi I am trying to learn and implement react context. I have encountered a bug when tryin to update user context.

I have a login page and when a user logs in, the email address and the user name should be updated in the user context.

When I click on submit, null information is stored in the context. But, when I click on submit the second time, I can see that the context is getting updated.

[image]
[image]

**authentication.component.jsx**

```
import Navigation from "../navigation/navigation.component";
import { Button, InputGroup, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { UserContext, setUser, setEmail } from "../../contexts/user.context";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import "./authentication.styles.scss";

const UserLogon = () => {
  const { setUser, setEmail } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [emailAddr, setEmailAddr] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log(emailAddr);
  }, [emailAddr, password]);

  const updateFormData = () => {
    setEmailAddr(emailAddr);
    setPassword(password);
    console.log("updated");
    console.log(emailAddr);
    console.log(password);
  };

  const saveEmail = (event) => {
    setEmailAddr(event.target.value);
    //console.log(emailAddr);
  };

  const savePassword = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
    //console.log(password);
  };

  const verifyUserHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const baseURL = `http://localhost:4000/verify_user?email=${emailAddr}&password=${password}`;

    axios
      .post(baseURL)
      .then((response) => {
        //console.log("User verified");
        if (response.data[2] === "verified") {
          console.log("user verified");
          var email = response.data[0];
          var name = response.data[1];
          console.log("email: ", email);
          console.log("name: ", name);
          setEmail(email);
          setUser(name);
        } else {
          console.log("user auth error");
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth-container">
      <div className="auth-login">
        <div className="login-info">
          <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
              <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                onChange={saveEmail}
              />
              <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                We'll never share your email with anyone else.
              </Form.Text>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={savePassword}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
              <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={verifyUserHandler}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserLogon;
```

**user.context.jsx**

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
 
export const UserContext = createContext({
  currentUser: null,
  setCurrentUser: () => null,
  userEmail: null,
  setUserEmail: () => null,
});
 
export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState(null);
 
  const setUser = (user) => {
    console.log("USER: user context before", currentUser);
    setCurrentUser(user);
    console.log("USER: user context after", currentUser);
  };

  const setEmail = (email) => {
    console.log("EMAIL: user context before", userEmail);
    setUserEmail(email);
    console.log("EMAIL: user context after", userEmail);
  };
 
  const value = { setUser, setEmail, currentUser, userEmail };
 
  return <UserContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

Any help is appreciated.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React state setter function is async which means that at the moment you `console.log` it's not yet updated in your state : )

Try this to validate:

```js
const setUser = (user) => {
  setCurrentUser(user)
  console.log({ currentUser, user })
  // To better debug wrap vars in { }
}

const setEmail = (email) => {
  setUserEmail(email)
  console.log({ userEmail, email })
}
```

More info from docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: I tried the edits. Still the current user is null. 
{currentUser: null, user: 'Abhiram'}


  If I click on the submit button the second time.
  {currentUser: 'Abhiram', user: 'Abhiram'}

Comment: That's what I mean my friend : )
You don't need to rely on that console.log since it's not it's current state.

This
 {currentUser: null, user: 'Abhiram'} means it's working. currentUser(before update is null), when calling the function it's 'Abhiram' . You better validate on context consumer for currentUser and email :))

Comment: thank you for clarifying the issue. I tired to print the use the user and email values in another page (profile page), but the results are null.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xXBUeWu8vhgOAo3r0c-6wI1qNjS9S1D9/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RlnYlPWUNhWQlQSvcbyN3cILF0ewrCES/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the intitial values from createContext. I think it might be causing your issue.

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
 
export const UserContext = createContext();
 
export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState(null);
 
  const setUser = (user) => {
    setCurrentUser(user);
    console.log(currentUser);
  };
 
  const setEmail = (email) => {
    setUserEmail(email);
    console.log(userEmail);
  };
 
  const value = { setUser, setEmail, currentUser, userEmail };
 
  return <UserContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: I tried removing the initial values. But the result is the same.

Comment: Please add the rest of the component where you login.

Comment: Thank you. I tried logging usernames and email using useEffect and as D3Portillo said that due to it's asynchronous nature, I cannot rely on console log. Context is getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add useEffect console log to context provider to check when the state is changing.

```
  useEffect(() => {
   console.log("User", currentUser);
   console.log("Email", userEmail);
  }, [currentUser, userEmail]);
```

As you can see from [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-parm-1o2jzl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) it works properly